# MemoryConstrained[] does not work as expected

Tags: memory

I am trying to put an upper limit on how much memory the kernel can use. For this, I am using the MemoryConstrained function in Mathematica. But this behaves very weirdly as shown below.

```
In[1]:= MaxMemoryUsed[exp = MemoryConstrained[Range[10^9], 10^6, "Error"];]
Out[1]= 8000000336
```

the value of exp is "Error" as expected but then why does the MaxMemoryUsed function show more than what was allowed 10^6 (1Mb)? I also confirmed using system monitor that the memory actually went up to 8Gb.

What is the correct procedure to limit the max allowed memory to a kernel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `MemoryConstrained ` only checked in the main evaluation loop?  That means `Range` has to finish before `MemoryConstrained` can stop the evaluation?

Comment: This attempt to allocate before putting the memory constraint into effect is a known deficiency. I added this example to the report along with a suggestion for how we might remedy it. But I do not know whether there might be ill effects from such a change.